# Finding the type of object in MapBasic (MapInfo)

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am trying to write a MapBasic function to check whether or not an object can be used with the Overlap/AreaOverlap functions - I need to tell whether it's a closed shape or a line/arc/point/text object.

I have two questions.

1. Is there an existing function that will do this?
2. Why doesn't this work?

   ```
   Function IsObjectRegion(ObjAlias As Alias) As Logical
       Dim ObjectType As SmallInt
       Note OBJ_TYPE_POINT    ' This popup is displayed correctly
       Note "Crash Now."      ' This doesn't display. 
                              ' Instead you get an error that says "could not convert data".
       ObjectType = ObjectInfo(ObjAlias, OBJ_INFO_TYPE)
       Do Case ObjectType
           Case OBJ_TYPE_REGION
               IsObjectRegion = True
               print "Object WAS a region"
           Case OBJ_TYPE_RECT 
               IsObjectRegion = True
               print "Object WAS a region"
           Case OBJ_TYPE_ROUNDRECT 
               IsObjectRegion = True
               print "Object WAS a region"
           Case OBJ_TYPE_ELLIPSE
               IsObjectRegion = True
               print "Object WAS a region"
           Case Else
               IsObjectRegion = False
               print "Object was NOT a region"
       End Case
   End Function
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to be passing an object variable into the function, not an alias which is just a column reference.

```
Function IsObjectRegion(selObj As Object) As Logical
Dim ObjectType As SmallInt

ObjectType = ObjectInfo(selObj, OBJ_INFO_TYPE)
Do Case ObjectType
...
```

If you wanted to test this out with the currently selected object, you could call the function like this:

```
    Dim test As Logical
    Dim testObject As Object
    testObject = Selection.Obj
    test = IsObjectRegion(testObject)

    Note test
```

This should return True/False.

James

Comment: Thanks James. When you put it like that it seems so obvious!

Comment: A good place to post about MapInfo problems is the MapInfo-L. Very helpful people who know a lot about MapInfo and MapBasic. The address is http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l

Comment: Yeah, I've posted there before and pretty much always got a good answer. I've only just found out about this site though after using StackOverflow for ages, so I thought I'd give it a go. Looking good so far!

Comment: Yeah try and cross post to here as well, we need as much traffic here as we can.